# Recursive bash function vs iterative "eval" string building: Which performs better?

Tags: bash, time-complexity

I am creating this function to make multiple grep's over every line of a file. I run it as following:

```
 cat file.txt | agrep string1 string2 ... stringN
```

The idea is to print every line that contains all the strings: string1, string2, ..., stringN, I followed this two approaches the fist is a recursive method :

```
agrep () {
    if [ $# = 0 ]; then
        cat
    else
        pattern="$1"
        shift
        grep -e "$pattern" | agrep "$@"
    fi
}
```

by the other hand I have a second approach related with an iterative method, since i am using a for method :

```
function agrep () {  
  for a in $@;  do
    cmd+=" | grep '$a'";
  done ;
  while read line ; do
    eval "echo "\'"$line"\'" $cmd";
  done;
}
```

This two approaches works very well but i would like to know if someone can tell me which one is the more efficient? and also if it's posible if there is a way to measure this in bash?, since i consider that i don't have the enough experience to determine this because i don't know if bash it's a programming language that works better with iterative methods or recursive methods or maybe if it's to expensive to use eval.

This two functions are designed to work with large texts and process every line of the texts, I really would appreciate any explanation or advice of this.

This is an example of text file called risk:

```
1960’s. Until the 1990’s it was a purely theoretical analysis of the
problem of function estimation from a given collection of data.
In the middle of the 1990’s new types of learning algorithms
(called support vector machines) based on the developed t
```

and then if i run:

```
cat risk | agrep Until
```

I get:

```
1960.s. Until the 1990.s it was a purely theoretical analysis of the
```

but by the other hand if i run:

```
cat risk | agrep Until new
```

prints nothing since there inst any line with that two strings, this was a function designed to clarify the usage of the function.

Comment: Do you know about the `time` unix command? It mights help you.

Comment: You can get a good feel for your answer by counting the number of subprocesses/subshells created by each of your methods. (remember a pipe spawns a subshell of its own and each call to a utility will spawn its own subprocess)

Comment: Yes i know about this command, i consider that can be useful, but should I use it like this?  time  cat file.txt | agrep string1 string2 ... stringN, thanks for the support.

Comment: If you cared about performance, why use `cat file.txt` at all? `cat file.txt | foo` is a highly inefficient way of writing `foo <file.txt`, with semantics that are nothing but worse for performance (since it means that `foo` has only a pipe handle rather than a direct handle on the file itself, and a separate `cat` process is invoked to read from the handle and write to the input side of the pipe).

Comment: Anyhow, the big risk with the `eval` approach is security-related, not performance. And it *does* carry security risks, and you absolutely shouldn't use it.

Comment: ...of the two forms you gave, your first, recursive, approach is by far the preferable one from a security perspective.

Comment: Ok I will consider your security suggestions but i would like to know the risk's of to use eval.

Comment: BTW, your `while read line` code is buggy -- look at what it does to lines with literal backslashes. It'll also potentially trim leading and trailing whitespace. `while IFS= read -r line; do` is safer, and `printf '%s\n' "$line"` on the inside of the loop -- that way you don't have your `echo` eat lines containing only `-n`, for instance.

Comment: Also, iterating over `$@` is equivalent to `$*` -- it performs string-splitting and glob expansion; if you want safety, you need `"$@"`, with quotes.

Comment: ...re: correcting the `while read` loop (though there's no reason to be using it all rather than embedding `cat`, if you expect your inputs to be large enough for its improved throughput to overcome the overhead of launching an external tool), see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: As another aside: The `function` keyword is a bashism, which (unlike many other extensions) adds no functionality (other than the ability to use function names disallowed by POSIX-standard rules) over the standardized, conventional syntax. Consider getting in the habit of declaring functions without the `function` keyword, as simply `agrep() {`, which will make your code compatible with a wider range of shells.

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with the comments and answers that have already informed you of the pitfalls of your current approach.

Based on the [suggestion made by karakfa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36452398/2088135), I would suggest using a function that calls awk, along these lines:

```
agrep() {
    awk 'BEGIN {
        # read command line arguments and unset them
        for (i = 1; i < ARGC; ++i) {
            strings[i] = ARGV[i]
            ARGV[i] = ""
        }
    }
    {
        for (i in strings) {
            # if the line does not match, skip it
            if ($0 !~ strings[i]) next
        }
        # print remaining lines
        print
    }' "$@"
}
```

This passes in all of the arguments to the function as arguments to awk, which would normally treat them as filenames. Each argument is added to a new array, `strings` and removed from `ARGV` before any lines of input are processed.

Use it like this:

```
agrep string1 string2 string3 < file
```

Comment: Thus, I'd tend to suggest having your awk script look directly at the `ARGV` list.

Comment: @user138717 thanks for updating your question, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

both are inefficient but since grep is very fast you may not be noticing. A better approach is switching to `awk`

```
awk '/string1/ && /string2/ && ...  && /stringN/' file
```

will do the same in one iteration.

Comment: Much, *much* better; this is also avoiding the security risks implicit in `eval`.

Comment: thanks but this isn't a function the point it's to have a function in order to avoid writing all the command every time that i want to search for some strings.

Comment: @user138717, ...but there's no reason a function that can't be written that passes a list of regexes as arguments to an awk script which tests each line of input against all of them. The theory is sound, even if this particular implementation is inadequate.

Comment: I went ahead and made a shell function based on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Security

The `eval`-based approach has a critical flaw: It allows code injection via maliciously formed strings being searched for. Thus, for the two as-given, the recursive approach is the only reasonable option for real-world production scenarios.

Why is the `eval` approach insecure? Look at this code for a moment:

```
cmd+=" | grep '$a'";
```

What happens if `a=$'\'"$(rm -rf ~)"\''`?

A corrected implementation might modify this line to read as follows:

```
printf -v cmd '%s | grep -e %q' "$cmd" "$a"
```

---

#### Performance

Your recursive approach does all its recursing while setting up a pipeline of length proportional to the number of arguments passed to `agrep`. Once that pipeline has been set up, the shell itself is out of the way (all ongoing operations are performed by the `grep` processes), and the performance overhead is exactly identical to the performance of the pipeline itself.

Thus, for a sufficiently large input file, the performance of the setup stage becomes effectively nil, and the relevant performance difference will be that between `cat` and a `while read` loop -- which `cat` will handily win for inputs large enough to overcome its startup costs.

Comment: The point of my question it's about complexity and efficiency, I don't need to care about to use some bad strings since I am the only person that use this small function to look for some strings, but thanks any how, i will consider your advices.

Comment: Code that has security flaws is code that **doesn't actually perform its intended function across the full range of possible inputs.** Which is to say that it's code that's incorrect. Why would you consider something that isn't a correct solution a plausible candidate for performance evaluation?

Comment: @user138717, ...that said, I've added an addendum speaking to performance characteristics.

Comment: @user138717, ...and also an edit showing how to close the vulnerability while still using `eval`.

Comment: I've learnt a few things around security with bash from @CharlesDuffy and such ignorance towards education is quite obtuse